# Cubesumming in haskell

Tags: haskell

Haskell has the sum function

```
sum :: Num a => [a] -> a
```

Which can be nicely composed to sum a matrix by

```
sum . map sum :: Num a => [[a]] -> a
```

Going deeper, however, such as summing a cube, creates the restriction Num [a]

```
sum . map sum . map sum :: (Num a, Num [a]) => [[[a]]] -> a
```

Which, if you think about it, is natural. So with the former attempt to define the sumcube function blowing up in one's face, we need to find a different path. One such attempt would be:

```
sum . map sum . map (map sum) :: Num a => [[[a]]] -> a
```

Which seems nowhere as natural as the summatrix function.

In my quest to posessing the mental tools for problem solving in Haskell, I am interested in knowing how to tackle this problem of summing a structure of any depth by, say, stacking `map sum`s as in my third code example. Is this at all possible? And in that case, how would you do it?

Comment: Did you try `sum . map (map sum)`?

Comment: sum . map (map sum) :: (Num [b], Num b) => [[[b]]] -> [b]

Comment: If you are interested in fast operations on numeric matrices, you should probably use vector, repa, hmatrix, or similar packages.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll have to work from the inside out. When you have a function `f` for summing a data structure, then `sum . map f` is the way to sum a list of those data structures.

```
                     sum  :: Num a =>   [a]   -> a
           sum . map sum  :: Num a =>  [[a]]  -> a
sum . map (sum . map sum) :: Num a => [[[a]]] -> a
```

Comment: that is a nice way to look at it

Comment: I choose this as my accepted answer because it explains the problem in the best way.

Answer (score 14):

How about typeclasses?

```
class Summable a where
  total :: a -> Int

instance Summable Int where
  total = id  

instance Summable x => Summable [x] where
  total = sum . map total  

total ([[[1,2,3],[4,5]],[[6],[7,8,9,10]]] :: [[[Int]]])
--55
```

Comment: Interesting aspect indeed. Does scale nicely

Comment: really nice - sadly i can't fav answers - this is a concept i want to keep in mind.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this? Assumes associativity, but adding new layer is simple

```
 sum . concat . concat :: Num c => [[[c]]] -> c
```

Comment: Concat was actually my motivation for the question. Concat composes wonderfully which  sum doesn't, i guess because sum has a type restriction. Point taken.

Comment: `concat` removes layers from the outside of the type, whereas `sum` has to remove layers from the inside. Contrast `concat . concat` and `sum . map sum` with `concat . map concat`.

Comment: @MagnusKronqvist: The difference is that `concat` operates entirely on the lists, while `sum` operates on the elements. With the latter you always have to start with the innermost list, but any "list of lists" can be concatenated. This is the fundamental concept behind lists being a monad, incidentally.

Answer (score 1):

It seems most natural to me to define an additional dimension's `sum` in terms of the previous dimension's `sum`.

```
-- given sum :: Num a => [a] -> a

sum2 :: [[a]] -> a
sum2 = sum . map sum

sum3 :: [[[a]]] -> a
sum3 = sum . map sum2

sum4 :: [[[[a]]]] -> a
sum4 = sum . map sum3
```

This is basically the same idea as what Sjoerd said. If you want to only use `map` and `sum` and *not* refactor common subexpressions into useful names...then use equational reasoning to replace the custom functions `sum2`, `sum3`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First, there's [Template Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Template_Haskell) (GHC extension though). Or you could use a `data` which supports arbitrary deep list nesting like that:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node [Tree a]

sumTree (Leaf x) = x
sumTree (Node xs) = (sum . map sumTree) xs

main = print $ sumTree $ Node [ Node [Leaf 3, Leaf 4, Leaf 5]
                              , Node [Leaf 1, Leaf 4, Leaf 2]]
```

Which will print `19` here. However this does not ensure that all leaves have the same nesting depth and i don't know how to build this from lists.